# Is there a Display Manager for ultra-widescreen monitors in Linux?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

**Use-Case**

So in my daily life, I use Ubuntu 20.x for coding, chatting, browsing but also most notably for online calls with screen sharing.

So I use an ultrawide monitor and I get annoyed with the window resizing.
Also, I couldn't find a proper solution for screen sharing during online calls, as I only got the option to choose a monitor or a program to share.

**Source**

Now I found a video of the so-called Dell Display Manager: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPcMzY6Ps44
This Display Manager (to my knowledge) is only available on Windows.

**Question/what I am looking for**

So my question is: Is there a Display Manager that

- can split the screen into a minimum of 3
- when moving a Window into these split screens, its size gets adjusted or something similar. In other words, it should be user friendly and intuitive.
- can split the screen in such a way, that online call applications like zoom, teams, slack can interpret the screen as an option to share. This way I hope to bypass the selection of one single application to share.
- nice to have would be that the split-screen can be resized and moved or something similar.
- I expect the solution to not be tied to a specific monitor, hardware or hardware brand.

**EDIT**

**Info about my System**

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l
- DM: gdm3

Comment: Please be precise with details; what do you mean by 20.x?  What DE are you using?  You've tagged KDE so are you using KDE/Plasma as your desktop & `sddm` as your current DM?   If you want a system that perfectly meets your needs; grab one, configure it or just fork it & create exactly what you want if you're a coder; it's open source.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have added the Ubuntu Version, the DM Version and removed the wrong tag. About forking it: I'm a web Developer and only a Ubunutu User. I neither have the time nor knowledge to recode how the screens and Windows are managed in Linux. My question basically is: If you have an ultra-widescreen monitor and Ubuntu, how to get to a behaviour as described. I mean is this problem that uncommon for Ubuntu users? How do they solve it?

Comment: + for a very relevant question, I have the exact same question for both Linux and Windows, On Windows I found areaToShare, that is an app, with a transparent window that allows me to mark an area on the screen to share. Have not found similar simple solution for Liunx yet.
But it is a year ago you asked this question, did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I also use a Laptop do I can jump to that for screen sharing, but that's not optimal. I also haven't looked for a solution for a while. Its weird for me that so few people struggle with this, since I believe that there are many developers A. rich enough to afford a big screen and B. use Linux for job and windows in private.